# Cant save images to folder on linux server with .net core api

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, permissions

when i try to upload an image to my linux server via my .net core api i get following error:

> Access to the path '/var/aspnetcore/wwwroot/Images/ProfileImages/8e445865-... is denied. System.IO.IOExpection: Permission denied.

The user in my service is 'www-data' for the api.

Can someone explain me how to grant access to the complete 'Image' folder for this user?

Comment: Check your upload folder permissions. And add everyone's permission to upload the folder, and test it again. Don't forget to remove everyone's permission when the test is over.

Comment: Did you figured out what permissions are safe to give in this case?